# How can I export a JSON object to Excel using Nextjs/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, export-to-excel

I have an endpoint that retrieves a json object like the following:

```
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"temaIndicador": "Indian",
"codigo": "001",
"observaciones": "Interactions Specialist tertiary Regional Tennessee",
"activo": "SI",
"urlImagen": "http://placeimg.com/640/480",
"color": "cyan",
"createdAt": "2022-01-26T18:48:36.002Z"
]
```

And I want to implement a button that will allow the user to export the data to multiple formats, including Excel (.xlsx) but I don't really know were to start.
I've already seen libraries that realize this, but I don't feel comfortable because they usually have less than 1.5k downloads per week.

My purpose is to export an Excel document with a simple table where the headers are going to be the attributes of the objects.

Comment: You can start by export the json as a csv file (comma seperated, or semicolumn seperated). The first line will be the names of the columns.

Comment: [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) has 774,337 weekly downloads. [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) has 454,689 downloads this week. [excel-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-export) is 6 years old, but still had 37,945 weekly downloads.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use xlsx third-party library.

```
npm install xlsx
```

Using Library: (use one of the following lines to import) -

```
import XLSX from "xlsx";
```

or

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

Download function trigger at button click(pass data as argument):

```
downloadExcel = (data) => {
    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Sheet1");
    //let buffer = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "buffer" });
    //XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "binary" });
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "DataSheet.xlsx");
  };
```

Download Button: (function call: you should modify it as per your requirement, below one is React Class Component implementation, that's why I used `this`  )

```
<button onClick={()=>this.downloadExcel(data)}>
    Download As Excel
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I needed

Comment: It shows the following error "Attempted import error: 'xlsx' does not contain a default export (imported as 'XLSX')"

Comment: import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

Comment: note that `xlsx` on npm is not being updated. Last version was published over a year ago: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx?activeTab=versions.

The official docs recommends installing it by installing tarball directly: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/nodejs/#installation

Answer (score 14):

Based on the accepted answer, in case someone is getting the "Attempted import error: 'xlsx' does not contain a default export (imported as 'XLSX')" error, try importing using the following:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

Hope it helps.