# Export data to Excel on Next.js page not working on production

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, export-to-excel, xlsx, sheetjs

I have some data coming from MongoDB in my Next JS app and inside one of the pages. The data will be in the shape of an array of objects like the below:

```
const data = [
    { _id: '63769f3609144b01779e75e6', name: '', email: '', description: 'Visitor' },
    { _id: '6375b7b609144b01779e75c9', name: '', email: '', description: 'Resident (Homeowner),Businessowner,Work in the City' }
]
```

I use the [XLSX package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) in my page to export these data on a click of a button. Here is my function that is triggered by the click of a button:

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

....
const handleExcelExport = () => {
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new()
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data)
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Comments");
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, "survey-data.xlsx");
}
```

This works perfectly fine on the **dev environment** and I get the Excel file:

[image]

However, when I push my code to production (Heroku), after I click the button, an Excel file is being downloaded, but when I try to open it, Excel complains that the file is corrupt and cannot open it.

[image]

I can change the extension to xls from xlsx and then I am able to open the corrupt file which looks like this:

[image]

I have watched many YouTube videos, read articles and checked out many SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871254/how-can-i-export-a-json-object-to-excel-using-nextjs-react) and even though I am using the same code, but it fails on Prodcution. Am I missing any steps to make it work on production?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else out there has the same problem as I had, I ended up using [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) and [xlsx-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate) libraries instead of XLSX library that I originally used.

I found [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-goldwasser-888e9?file=/src/App.js:1190-1279) which helped me with implementing the logic to save my data as Excel using the two libraries above.